# Async Execution Wait For Any

Tags: .net

Have some method, which is called sync like:

```
tasks.ForEach(p=> Proccess(p));

void Proccess(){
   //do some long running work
}
```

How can i do something like, on pseudocode:

```
tasks.ForEach(p=> Async(Proccess(p));
WaitForAny();
```

Here i want to call tasks async, and wait for any execution end.(not for all).
Can u plz help me, without parallel tasks from .net 4.

Comment: Is the above your pseudo code? IF it is the actual code, can you post the definition of the tasks object?

Comment: a bit edited, they are just functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `Task.WaitAny`

```
Task[] tasksToWaitFor = new Task[itemsToCall.Length];
foreach (int i = 0; i < itemsToCall.Length; i++)
{
    var itemToCall = itemsToCall[i];
    tasksToWaitFor[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => itemToCall.Call());
}

await Task.WaitAny(tasksToWaitFor);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270672.aspx

Comment: it is .net 4. i can use only 3.5 or 2

Comment: If at all possible I would try to migrate to .NET 4 or .NET 4.5. Otherwise you will have to roll your own version of Tasks using Threads or Backgroundworkers